# Wamp does not execute php code

Tags: php, wamp

It happened today!
The `wamp` server does not execute my php code.

It worked fine yesterday!

This first screen-shot shows my project. It seems blank , but I wrote `<? php echo "s" ?>` on that. 
The second screen-shot is source PHP code of my project into Google Chrome.

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: did you set the server online?

Comment: First recommendation: Never put spaces in folders. The 'cosmetics' aren't nice and it's not preferred to have the spaces in the url. Second thing I have to ask: is the server actually online? As I can see no WAMP icon in your traybar. Can you check your output (in like Firebug or the Chrome Console) and see if it actually echoes something?

Comment: @PimVerlangen Aside from cosmetics and personal preference, there's no real reason one can't use spaces in paths. Also note that the folder in question seems to be the root of the project, so the spaces in that name won't likely translate to the actual site. That said; I agree with your preference and the reason for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to open your page not via `file://...` but with

`http://127.0.0.1/path/to/your/server/document/root/your-script.php`

or

`http://localhost/path/to/your/server/document/root/your-script.php` 
.

By default on `xampp/wamp` installations this path is `<install_folder>/xampp/` or `<install_folder>/wamp/` and in this path resides the `document root` (folder with name `www` for `wamp` installation or `htdocs` for `xampp`).

Also it is general good idea to replace spaces in your sub-folder with slashes `-` or underscore `_`, however this is not mandatory for your scripts to work.

Answer (score 1):

please start the wamp server to desktop or bottom bar.
Then put `localhost/` put in url.

example: `localhost/phpmyfristprojet/`

The WAMP server running if there is green signal.

Answer (score 0):

in wordpress i had to do in .htaccess

```
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
AddType application/x-httpd-php php php4 php3 html htm
```

Explain: I comment the first line and added the second